# How to fetch ip address and status of services from a list of hostname in TXT file

Tags: powershell

I want to add ip address in the table where status of services is fetched of the list of host names saved in TXT file . One host may contain more than one service .services name starts with I . How I do it.

```
 $servers=Get-Content c:\servers.txt
    $servers|Foreach-Object{Get-Service -ComputerName $_ -Name I*}  | Select-Object -Property  ServiceName, Status | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlhead | Out-String
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide more details about what you want to achieve ? Also, I assume your host name list is contained into the $servers variable ? Did you already fed a variable with IPs ? My guess would be to go for a custom object/array containing the IPs and services info...

Comment: I have scripted so that services status is being sent through mail , the only thing I need to add ip address of the different hostnames in the table I am sending , one host may contain more than one service

Comment: I don't want to give custom array of IPs . Even if I add a new hostname in my file I want to fetch status of that too

Comment: I was not talking about a static array of IP. Please check my proposed answer, where I use an array and a custom PS object to create a custom table containing the requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, here is the script I would use for such a scenario :

```
# Gettings the server list from text file
$servers = Get-Content c:\servers.txt

# Creating an empty array
$array = @()

# Starting the loop for each server in the list
foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
    # Getting the server's IP. Other methods could apply
    $IP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server").IPAddressToString

    # Getting the list of services
    $services = Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name I*

    # Starting the loop for each service in the list
    foreach ($service in $services)
    {
        # Creating a new PS object and adding values
        $Object = New-Object PSObject
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value $server
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "IP" -Value $IP
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Service" -Value $service.Name
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Status" -Value $service.Status

        #Feeding the array with the values
        $array += $Object
    }
}

# Now converting the array to HTML
$array | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlhead | Out-String
```

In the console, the $array would expand like this :

[image]

Please try and let us know if it suits your need. You may have to adapt according to your environment.

Hope this helps !

Comment: You could also use the native Powershell `Resolve-DnsName` cmd-let instead of the `[System.Net.Dns]` class. `$servers | ForEach-Object  {(Resolve-DnsName $_).IpAddress}`

Comment: @MrPowerUser indeed, but depending of the Powershell version the user has, this Cmdlet may not be available.

Comment: This doesn't fetch me Ipv4 address right ? I need IPv4 only so I'm using test-connection command , also is there a way I can fetch the service names from another TXT file instead of using I* . Ex :I have a host name in one file and the service for that host name in another file , I'll be inserting both the host name and services in same order